# Array variable key/value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently trying to use PHP to get some information from a csv file. I am using the following code and getting the following output;

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

$csvFile = '500.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
$keys = $csv[0];
$step = $csv[1];
foreach ($step as $k=>$v)
{
    $a = array("$keys[$k]");
    $b = array("$v");
    $c = array_combine($a, $b);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($c);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

and I get the output in individual arrays like;

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => bob
)
Array
(
    [last_name] => smith
)
Array
(
    [company_name] => bobs logs
)
```

and I want the output to be in one single array, displayed like;

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => bob
    [last_name] => smith
    [company_name] => bobs logs
)
```

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong it would be appriciated!

Comment: Since you have 3 arrays, you could just do https://repl.it/Cg3C `$a + $b + $c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_combine` function

> Returns the combined *array*, **FALSE** if the number of elements for each array isn't equal.

Your code creates a new array on each loop iteration.
To get a single array change your loop code as shown below:

```
...
$c = [];
foreach ($step as $k => $v)
{
    $c[$keys[$k]] = $v;    
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($c);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$a = array("$keys[$k]");
$b = array("$v");
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
```

To:

```
$c[$keys[$k]] = $v;
```

And do this after the loop:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($c);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function readCSV($csvFile)
{
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

$csvFile = '500.csv';
$csv     = readCSV($csvFile);
$keys    = $csv[0];
$step    = $csv[1];
$output = array();
foreach ($step as $k => $v) {
    $a = array("$keys[$k]");
    $b = array("$v");
    $c = array_combine($a, $b);
    $output = array_merge($output, $c);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

what changes did I make?
I took outside foreach those echo and print_r and added

```
$output = array_merge($output, $c);
```

Which merge every new array as a new element inside our $output array

then finally we print $output array.

This should be working as you want, anyway if you need to change something  in the future you can check array_merge function [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: You should *explain* your answer some more.